# Python wheel does not contain project after using bdist_wheel while __init__.py is in root

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel

I have a project that I want to distribute using a whl. I have a project tree that looks like this:

```
ProjectName
    ModuleFolder
       some_modules.py
    ModuleFolder2
        more_modules.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='ProjectName',
    version='1.0',
    author='Menno Manheim',
    author_email='mymail@example.com',
    description='Project description',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Now I am trying to create a wheel package like this:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

There is a whl package created, but it only contains one folder. It is named "ProjectName-1.0.dist.info" and in this folder I can see only these 1KB files:

```
MEDADATA
RECORD
top_level.txt
WHEEL
```

I expected that the whl file would contain the complete ProjectName tree including the root files.

What have I missed?

Btw. I am working in PyCharm and I am using a venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `find_packages()` function, does not find your packages because you did not declared your `ModuleFolder` and `ModuleFolder` as such.

You should insert `__init__.py` to both folders.

In addition, please note that the root folder is not a package so the `__init__` there is redundant.

Edit: Formal sample project structure from the python packaging Authority (PyPA) can be found [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject).

Comment: So is it not possible to have the main.py in the root?

Comment: You should have a main package (usually called the same as your project folder) below the root and put main.py there.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Just missing some root files that I now added as package data, but I will figure that out.